Restarted my computer and the display resolution changed
I restarted my computer and on the next boot I noticed the login screen was extremely zoomed in. When just on the desktop I can pan left to right now which wasn't something I did before and is needed just to get to various parts of the desktop. I tried exploring the settings and found it is reporting a Built-in display and an "Unknown Display" now. This made me believe it wasn't recognizing my original laptop display and I ran "xrandr --query".
The outputs of xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm panning 3840x1080+0+0
   1920x1080    144.00*+
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +

Which shows There are two displays Screen Zero and None-1-1. My built-in display is 1920x1080 144 refresh rate not the 3840x1080 144 refresh rate or the 1920x1080 with 60 refresh rate.
I looked in the logs to see if there was any indication of what was happening and found
multiple entries that are
[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

I also found these logs as well
 2:38:38 PM kernel: nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: BOE Technology Group Co., Ltd (DP-2): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-3:nvidia-auto-select"
 2:38:38 PM acpid: 1 client rule loaded
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA:     access.
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA:     access.
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA: Reserving 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (WW) NVIDIA:     '/var/run/nvidia-xdriver-0a8ed763' Permission denied
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (WW) NVIDIA: Failed to bind sideband socket to
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Unloading vesa
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Unloading fbdevhw
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Unloading fbdev
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Module "fb" already built-in
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) LoadModule: "fb"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Loading sub module "fb"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) modeset(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  124.42  1920 1920 1920 1920  1080 1080 1080 1080 (64.8 kHz eP)
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): Printing probed modes for output None-1-1
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output None-1-1
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): Output None-1-1 has no monitor section
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): ShadowFB: preferred NO, enabled NO
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): glamor initialization failed
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) modeset(G0): Refusing to try glamor on llvmpipe
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: kmsro: driver missing
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: MESA-LOADER: failed to open simpledrm: /usr/lib/dri/simpledrm_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
 2:38:38 PM Xorg:   ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
 2:38:38 PM Xorg:   compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.1
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (143, 144); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-3:nvidia-auto-select"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) NVIDIA(0):
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (==) NVIDIA(0):
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BOE Technology Group Co., Ltd (DFP-3): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BOE Technology Group Co., Ltd (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): BOE Technology Group Co., Ltd (DFP-3): connected
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
 2:38:38 PM kernel: nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: BOE Technology Group Co., Ltd (DP-2): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
 2:38:38 PM Xorg: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock

I'm just not sure how this started to begin with or how to fix this. I made sure my system was up to date. Please Help!
UPDATES

I learned that using this command
systemctl restart gdm

it restarts the driver and the resolution is corrected but upon a full system (turning on and off) restart it reverts back to the problem.

I've got similar symptoms here on a multi monitor setup. The worst of it is that maximized windows now extend over both montiors. That is not what I want, and I have no clue what to do to get back. But I know the last thing I did before reboot is to install updates.

What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

I found a solution to my problem using the information here. Apparently this is a common issue for NVIDIA devices udating to ubuntu 24.04 and this is the work around.
Use this command:
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

This is creating a config file that will run and add this to it:
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "None-1-1"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection

Where "None-1-1" is your phantom device name. Mine was as listed here. This config will ignore this monitor from setting up and thus xscreen zero only has one display listed in it.

Thank you for finding this answer. I can confirm it also fixed my multi-monitor setup. :-)
